# CCDirector setDeviceOrientation into cocos2d v2.0rc1

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

before to update my cocos2d 1.0.1 to 2.0rc1 in my app, I was calling [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation:(ccDeviceOrientation)currentOrientation]; into some scenes when detected one change on orientation and then load other scene in portrait or lanscape depending the currentOrientation.

But now I don't have any idea about how I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open AppDelegate.m and locate this method:

```
// Supported orientations: Landscape. Customize it for your own needs
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Return YES for all the orientations your app supports.

Answer (score 2):

`Orientation setOrientation (   Orientation     orientation )`
Callback by CCDirector for change device orientation.

The defination of orientation which CCDirector want change to.

Returns
The actual orientation of the application.